# Input doesn't respect flex container width

Tags: css, flexbox

I have an `input` in a flex container in Chrome and it does not respect the width of the container unless I add a `min-width: 0`. This seems to work properly in IE.

What is going on here?

```css
.input-with-button {
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.input-with-button input {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='input-with-button'>
  <div>Test</div>
</div>

<div class='input-with-button'>
  <input>
</div>
```

Comment: inputs have default width that are greater than 100px .. so replace flex-basis with width:100% and it should work

Comment: to be exact it is 169px ... and you won't find it in the default style by the way

Comment: IE also has a default width (149px) but the same issue doesn't occur. Just a flex-box implementation difference?

Comment: well since it's IE it's not a surprise :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason it works in IE is because it picks up the `flex-basis: 100%`, but it shouldn't.

The reason it overflows in Chrome (and should in IE), is that a flex item can't by default be smaller than its content since its `min-width` is set to `auto`, and in this case `form` elements, such as `input`, have a default width set using the browsers built it style sheet.

The reason `min-width: 0` works, is when set to `0` the flex item will, since its *flex-shrink* value is `1` (the default), be allowed to shrink, and does to adjust to its parent's width.

Stack snippet

```css
.input-with-button {
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.input-with-button input {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  min-width: 0;                        /*  added  */
}
```

```html
<div class='input-with-button'>
  <div>Test</div>
</div>

<div class='input-with-button'>
  <input>
</div>
```

---

As a side note, and as been mentioned in other answer(s), changing the default width of the element would of course also be an option, whether it is a `form` element or not.

Stack snippet

```css
.input-with-button {
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.input-with-button input {
  /*flex-basis: 100%;                     removed  */
  width: 100%;                        /*  added  */
}
```

```html
<div class='input-with-button'>
  <div>Test</div>
</div>

<div class='input-with-button'>
  <input>
</div>
```

Comment: this is the real answer, the other ones are avoiding the real issue by adding other styles ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` and `max-width: 100%;` to your input. Inputs have a default width which can be overwritten/limited that way.

```css
.input-with-button {
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.input-with-button input {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='input-with-button'>
  <div>Test</div>
</div>

<div class='input-with-button'>
  <input>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just use `min-width: 0`?

Comment: why `min-width: 0` ? What should that do - it only determines that the element has be be at least 0 wide???

Comment: @Johannes `min-width: 0` on a flex item does more than just tell it to be _at least 0 wide_, as you can see in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

This one works too

```css
.input-with-button {
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.input-with-button input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='input-with-button'>
  <div>Test</div>
</div>

<div class='input-with-button'>
  <input>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would `flex-basis` specify the initial length of the flex parent instead of the flex child?